slam toolbox: how to use interactive markers to fix heading of posegraph
I have a rosbag with tf and scan topics. I am able to create the map and save the posegraph, but after calling the slam toolbox node with the posegraph as a parameter, I'm not able to use the interactive markers to modify it.
I am launching the slam toolbox in rviz while the tf is being published by the rosbag and i am remapping scan topic. posegraph are visualized but when i move one and save the changes it says that i have not moved any marker.

We probably need more details: posting your code and the error would be a good idea. Plus any useful screenshots (if relevant).
